# OpenCV: src.size() == dst.size() && dst.type() == CV_32FC1 Error in .Net C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, opencv, wrapper, edge-detection

I have an image loaded from a video:

```
 Image<Gray, byte> imGray=cap.QueryGrayFrame();
```

Now, I want to use the cvCornerHarris function from openCv as following:

```
 Image<Gray, byte> harRes = new Image<Gray, byte>(imGray.Size);  
 CvInvoke.cvCornerHarris(imGray, harRes, 8, 3, 0.04);
```

But I get an cvException:

```
OpenCV: src.size() == dst.size() && dst.type() == CV_32FC1 Error
```

[image]

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deduce from the given exception, that the type of the destination image should be `CV_32FC1`.

In your case, the destination image is `harRes`, which you have declared as:

```
Image<Gray, byte> harRes = new Image<Gray, byte>(imGray.Size);
```

The type of this image is `CV_8UC1`.

It should be declared as:

```
Image<Gray, float> harRes = new Image<Gray, float>(imGray.Size);
```

Now its type is `CV_32FC1`, which is the type expected by the function `cvCornerHarris`.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about the C# wrapper, but in C++, you can change the pixel format using this line:

```
imGray.convertTo(A, CV_32F);
```

The error says, the size of images should match (which your code do the same) and the pixel format should be float32, which probably yours are not.

Comment: I looked for some examples in c# but unfortunately all the samples were instanced in c++. what's the origin of such exception? where am I going wrong?

Comment: The Harris Corner function needs a float image to work for. So, when you capture images (QueryGrayFrame), each pixel is (unsigned char), but most opencv functions requires floating point pixels. As I said I am not familiar with C# terminology and types but you need to convert them to floating point pixel type image

Comment: @Roozbeh... Harris corner detector in opencv expects input image as either 8 bit unsigned char or 32 bit float. But the output, i.e the cornerness map must be 32 bit float ONLY. You don't need to convert your input image to float.